# Is there any query in sqlite to choose a substring?

Tags: sqlite

Lets say I have a table Y with column X.

There is one row of "X" with the string "abcdefg", and another row with "qwerty".

Can I make a SELECT query in sqlite to choose the row which contains the substring "abcd" ?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE X LIKE "%abcd%"
```